# Query to Use a part of the value of a log field on my visualization on ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

Im new to ELK.

I have the log field "message" which implies for a value of "Polka time return is 120ms".

`message:"Polka time return is 120ms"`

I was able write a query to return the required match for return time for "Polka" in the "message" field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "appName": "Polkadot"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "message": "Polka time return*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However I am looking to only add the 120ms part onto a column on my visualization is there Any way that I can do that?

Any help is appreciated.